# My Karbon Smart Tab 7 Tornado EX SD CARD problem

Tags: external-sd, karbonn-smart-tab-7

My tab detects my sd card but the problem is.. it won't mount
can someone please help me..
I tried to format it into NTFS, ExFat, Fat32 but it doesn't work

Thank you for viewing!
Your answer is my gratitude

:)

Comment: Can you please [update your question](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/45999/edit) with some more details: Do you get any error messages? If so: can you quote some? You might also want to check your system logs aka `logcat` for details (depending on your device's Android-version, there are several logcat apps on the playstore; alternatively, `adb logcat` could be used with your tab connected to your computer via USB).